# Do Catholics believe Protestants are part of the Christian Faith?

Tags: catholicism, protestantism

My name is Dash. I am 16 and I am a Methodist Christian. I am currently learning about church history on my own and Ive come up with a few questions that have definitely been asked 1000 times.

Do Catholics believe Protestants are part of the Christian Faith?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! Can you please ask just one question at a time?

Comment: Okay. I’ll edit it so it asks only one

Comment: Sorry to close this question, Dash but I believe it has already been asked and the accepted answered is what you are looking for.